# Does row-echelon form of this matrix mean no solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

The original system of equations, for reference, was $$x+2y=8$$ $$x-y=2$$ $$x+y=4$$ I put the resulting matrix into row echelon form getting $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$ I tried to put this back into equation form, where column 1 is x, column 2 is y, and column 3 is the constant on the right of the equals sign. I got $$x=0$$ $$y=0$$ $$0=1$$ which obviously doesn't make sense. This also doesn't fit the original equations. Did I do something wrong (I can add my work if anyone requests it)? Or does this simply mean that there are no solutions?

Thanks! Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: This is thought to be a duplicate of another question I asked. This question is with a different system of equations, and ended up being a very different question; the first suggested solving by putting the matrix into row echelon form, and this one said I needed to learn how to put augmented matrices into row echelon form. Please don't close this as a duplicate, they are *not* the same.

Comment: Yep, that it you have the equation $0x+0y=1$ so no solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving overdetermined linear system with $3$ equations in $2$ unknowns](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932078/solving-overdetermined-linear-system-with-3-equations-in-2-unknowns)

Comment: @TheGeekGreek, I asked that question too, and they are very different. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the augmented system $$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&2&8\\1&-1&2\\1&1&4 \end{array}\right]$$ Then we get $$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&2&8\\1&-1&2\\1&1&4 \end{array}\right] \leadsto \left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&2&8\\0&-3&-6\\0&-1&-4 \end{array}\right]\leadsto\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&2&8\\0&1&2\\0&1&4 \end{array}\right]$$ But this is impossible to solve in two variables since from the third equation we get $y = 4$ and from the second $y = 2$.

Comment: Is there anything special I have to do to put an augmented matrix into row echelon form?

Comment: @heather No, not really, just the evaluation is a bit more trickier.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I'll figure it out. But the end result is that there are no solutions?

Comment: @heather Sorry, I just saw, what you did in your post. I would recommend to use such a vertical line to separate the left and the right side of the equations. It makes things easier. But yes, your conclusion was right, there exists no solution to this system.